# Matching texts by start and end in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I am doing a simple **webscraping** in R but I have a problent I cannot solve.

When I download the webscode, I need to extract a series of locations (mainly country names).

So, I have this text:

```r
text <- "Â  Agaon fasciatum Waterston (Life: Kingdom: Metazoa (animals); Phylum: Arthropoda; Class: Hexapoda; Order: Hymenoptera;Â  Superfamily: Chalcidoidea; Family: Agaonidae; Genus: Agaon) Agaon fasciatum Waterston, 1914, Agaon tridentatum Joseph 1959. Holotype in The Natural History Museum, London. Type locality:Â Uganda. Distribution Â  Cameroon, Gabon, Guinea, Uganda, Zambia. Biology Host fig: Ficus cyathistipula cyathistipula Warb. References Waterston, J. 1914. Notes on African Chalcidoidea. I. Bulletin of Entomological Research. 5:249-258. Credits Photographs Â© Jean-Yves Rasplus (INRA) or Â© Simon van Noort (Iziko Museums of South Africa). NextÂ  genus: AlfonsiellaÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â  Next species: Agaon gabonense"
```

and I need to extract the distribution, wchi corresponds to the words from `distribution` to the  `.` that indicates the end of the country list.

with

```r
str_locate(string = text, pattern = "Distribution")
```

I can detect the position of the word "Distribution."
I now that with someting like `".*\\."` I can detect the `.´ but when I try

```r
str_locate(string = text, pattern = "Distribution.*\\.")
```

I do not have any result.

Any solution? I now this should be easy, byt I do not find the answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance,

Antonio

Comment: What do you mean exactly that "I do not have any result." When I run the code on the example the first chunk returns "320 331" for start/end and the second returns "320 648" so they both return values. Are you sure this is reproducible with the example data given?

Answer (score 1):

### base R

```r
gsub(".*Distribution Â? *([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", text)
# [1] "Cameroon, Gabon, Guinea, Uganda, Zambia"
### or
gsub(".*(Distribution Â? *[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", text)
# [1] "Distribution Â  Cameroon, Gabon, Guinea, Uganda, Zambia"
```

or

```r
regmatches(text, gregexpr("Distribution Â? *[^.]+\\.", text))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Distribution Â  Cameroon, Gabon, Guinea, Uganda, Zambia."
```

If you use `gsub`, realize that if it is not found, the original `text` will be returned, unchanged. (So just check if `newtext != text` to make sure you found something.)

### stringr

```r
stringr::str_extract(text, "Distribution Â? *[^.]+\\.")
# [1] "Distribution Â  Cameroon, Gabon, Guinea, Uganda, Zambia."
```

and if you need the location string-indices,

```r
stringr::str_locate(text, "Distribution Â? *[^.]+\\.")
#      start end
# [1,]   320 375
```